# How to copy file from command line then paste in windows explorer

Tags: cmd, windows-explorer

I'm wondering if it's possible to mark a file as to be copied in command line, then paste it in explorer. Something like this:

First in command prompt to mark the file as to be copied,

> copy2explorer a.txt

Then in explorer simply press ctrl+v or click paste in folder's context menu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the filename on the Windows Clipboard yourself using [`SetClipboardData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649051.aspx) and the [`CF_HDROP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776902.aspx#CF_HDROP) clipboard data format.

Answer (score -1):

```
    system("copy C:\\example.txt E:\\example.txt");
    CopyFile(dest1, dest2, TRUE);
```

The last parameter sort of asks: Do not override the file if it exists ?
So if the argument is TRUE and a file with the same name exists there, function fails.
If it is FALSE, the file is copied, thus overriding the existing file.
If there is no such file present, whatever the last argument(TRUE or FALE), the copying is performed.
Actually simulating a Paste in windows explorer is a bit more tricky. You could try using the clipboard API.

Comment: I don't think this answer the question as it directly copy the file to a specified destination. The question is can we copy a file to the clipboard from command-line so that it can be pasted from somewhere else, in that case the window explorer.